# Why is a property undefined when it has been defined in a function?

Tags: javascript

I have a page with multiple buttons, each tied to the load function that are intended to open a new window and then set it customized to which button you click after the page has loaded.
I have been storing the options in objects, with the one in use under in `currentTile`. However, once the page loads, the text that appears says `undefined`, but haven't I already defined the `currentTile` in `load()`?

```
function tile(question, answer, points) {
    this.question = question;
    this.answer = answer;
    this.points = points;
}

var currentTile = {};

var testTile = new tile("How are you?", "Fine", 200);

function load(tile) {
    currentTile = tile;
    window.open("question.html", "_self");
}

function setText() {
    document.getElementById("qSlot").innerHTML = currentTile.question;
    document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = "" + currentTile.points + "";
}
```

`load()` is being called like this in the html: 
    `<td onclick="load(testTile)"></td>`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are you calling load function?

Comment: You are assigning the value passed to `load` (`tile`) to `currentTile`, but you are not showing how `load` is called. Presumable you are not passing any value to the function.

Comment: I am calling it in the html code, `<td onclick="load(testTile)"></td>`

Comment: `<td onclick="load(testTile)">` expects `testTitle` to be a js variable, (which is probably `undefined` when you're clicking the `td`, hence the error), try `<td onclick="load('testTile')">`

Comment: And then learn about [unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), it's better for everyone, including you if the person who follows you on the project knows where you live.

Comment: Are you sure `testTile` is still in scope within your HTML handler? If you’re not sure, please use the standard `addEventListener`.

Comment: @haxxxton I'm afraid the result is still the same.

Comment: you are looking for `currentTile.question` and `currentTile.points` in `setText` and just gave it a string, change the onclick to `<td onclick="load({question:'testTile',points:0})">` and you should see data coming through

Comment: Are you referring the JavaScript below the html or inside head? If you have referred this js file after your html, then try moving it to head section. I would recommend passing the required details in load function and then creating the tile object inside the load function.`on click="load('how are you','fine',200)"`

Comment: Where is `setText` called? What is `window.open("question.html", "_self");` supposed to do? Don't use multiple tabs with multiple scopes.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `window.open("question.html", "_self");` which is as good as reloading the page (assuming your current page is `question.html`). So when the page reloads, your JS code is going to execute all over again, including the statement `var currentTile = {};`. That's why you get `undefined` for `currentTile.question` and `currentTile.points`.

Instead of calling `window.open("question.html", "_self");` call `setText()` directly and it will show the text properly. (Where are you calling `setText()` right now?).